# Issue with callback FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I get this issue when i try to give tensorboard as a callback to the fit method. 
Does anybody know what the problem could be?

```
value_model.fit(inputs_original_buffer, targets_value, batch_size=mb_size, epochs=1, verbose=0, validation_split=0, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Full error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value training_2/SGD/Variable
>        [[Node: training_2/SGD/Variable/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_2/SGD/Assign"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Answer (score 0):

Some parameter related to your model has not been initialized. It would be good if you could you also mention how you are defining tensorboard object and also give a glimpse of the model.